# Random select from CSV Dataset config in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

For my script I have a CSV file as follow,

**Job_Id.csv**

```
406176
406185
406193
406194
406196
406198
406199
406201
406204
406205
406206
406211
```

**CSV Data set configuration**

[image: I am]

**HTTP Request :**

[image]

Is there any way I can select multiple random job id like may be if I declared `${__Random(2,5,)}`, it is going to pick the corresponding number from the list and pass it as follow,
for example if the above number is 2 as a outcome then it is going to select, `406176 & 406185`

```
{"jobId":[406176,406185]}
```

and in the next iteration if it is 3 then,

```
{"jobId":[406193,406194,406196]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the CSV Data Set Config.

1. Remove it completely
2. Add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request which sends this query
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def position = vars.getObject('position') ?: 0

   def random = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(2, 5)

   def lines = new File('test.csv').readLines()

   def reset = false

   def end = (position as int) + random
   if (end >= lines.size()) {
       end = lines.size() - 1
       reset = true
   }
   lines = lines.collect { entry -> entry as int }[position as int..end]

   vars.put('MULTI_JOB_ID1', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(lines).toPrettyString())

   if (reset) {
       end = 0
   }

   vars.putObject('position', end)
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Working with collections](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)